# Retirar fade de imagem

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transição

Estou com um site em mãos e preciso tirar o efeito de fade das fotos pois o cliente não quer que fique escuro quando passa o mouse sobre ela.
Como sou novo na área gostaria de saber que propriedade é essa, se é javascript, jQuery ou no proprio CSS pra poder encontrar em que parte do código está e desabilitar.

O site em questão é o http://www.astmetal.com.br/ e as imagens são as da seção 'nossos produtos'.

Comment: Está no CSS esse efeito. O _zoom_ que dá na imagem, está nessa classe `.thumb-info:hover img`. Já o efeito "escuro", está nessas duas classes `.thumb-info .thumb-info-wrapper:after` e `.thumb-info:hover .thumb-info-wrapper:after`

Comment: conseguiu fazer o que precisava?

Comment: acabei de testar e deu certo! Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Para fazer com que a imagem não fique mais escura ao passar o mouse você pode sobrescrever a regra do CSS colocando esse codigo abaixo no seu arquivo `custom.css`

```
.thumb-info .thumb-info-wrapper:after {
  background: unset;
}
```